# Dual Boot - Booting Ubuntu brings me to Grub Command Line - New User

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, grub2

Greetings AskUbuntu community !

I have a ASUS X55 (Intel(R) Core i5-5200 CPU @ 2.20GHz with 8GB RAM) I currently have Windows 10 , Version 1607.

Last week I had Ubuntu running on my computer however it was slightly buggy so I decided to remove it and try to re install it. I removed it, however I am having extreme difficulty trying to put it back on. I've watched countless YouTube installation videos , tried RUFUS , UUI and I still cant get it to work. I've spent 2-3 hours trying to solve this. I am new to Ubuntu so im hoping the community can help me with this one so I can pay it forward further down the line.

I also checked the hashes for my Ubuntu 16.04.1 iso and those are fine

When I write the iso to a USB and then attempt to boot from USB using 
(settings >Update and security > recovery > advanced startup) I am brought to a grub prompt grub>.

What the heck can I do to fix this ? This is beginning to really irritate me because I have no idea what I can google to remedy this problem.

Any help would be appreciated !

I have also tried booting into BIOS and changing the boot order so ubuntu is #1 but this brings the same problem I outlined above.

Thanks - KG

Answer (score 0):

You say you have windows 10 On your computer If I understand you,you also want to install ubuntu 16.04 on a partition and had it on once.
In windows 10 open the control panel click on Administrative tools on that window click computer management once in there click disc management. If you don't see it,click arrow infront of storage,once you see it  click disk management.Wait for your drive to show Part C: should be your windows 10 the partition you want Ubuntu to go should be re formated as to make it clean for installing your Ubuntu. If thats not right let us know.If you have installed Ubuntu 16.04 to a second drive reformat it then try a clean reinstall.

Comment: So if im understanding you correctly you want me to format my C: drive ? Wont I loose all of my information ?I have two drives a OSCB) drive and a UUI (D:) drive with 323GB and 560GB respectively. Is there a way I can install Ubuntu on to the D: drive ? Both of these are inside my computer. They are not external.

Comment: No do not format the C: drive ! Start your computer to open widows 10 find and open your control panel, in there click on Administrative Tools, in there click on (Computer management), in there click (Disk Management).

Answer (score 0):

Are you booting into grub rescue? Try running  `grub> set pager=1` Then `grub> ls` find where /boot/grub is located and make sure it is located in the proper place. Grub must be located on the boot sector of your HDD and not on a partition such as /dev/sda1.

Comment: What do you mean by "grub must be located on the boot sector " where do I look to find the boot sector ?

Comment: I just tried those commands. I entered grub>set pager=1 and then grub>ls (list). After I entered the commands this is what happened (hd0) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt5)(hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3)(hd1,gpt2)(hd1,gpt1) why are there so many hard drives ?

Comment: @MRS_ROBOT First question on boot sector, You need a boot partition as in (a separate partition dedicated for boot loader) and second question “Why do I have so many hard drives” you don’t, those are the partitions of one hard drive.